# SVG as background image

Tags: css, svg, background

I'm exporting a vector (logo) from Illustrator as SVG (1.1)
The vector has no gradient or transparency.

When I use the SVG as background image in my CSS
Nothing is shown but when I visit the image link (http://www.something.com/logo.svg) it shows me the image perfectly.

The CSS

```
#site-header {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 62px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2000;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #758391;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(6, 8, 8, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(6, 8, 8, 0.15);
}

#site-header #logo {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    width: 10%;
    min-width: 48px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 40px;
    margin: 12px 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#site-header #logo a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("img/logo.svg") no-repeat center center;
}
```

The HTML

```
<header id="site-header">
    <hgroup id="logo">
        <a href="#">
            <h1>
                <span class="hide">some hidden content</span>
            </h1>
        </a>
    </hgroup>
</header>
```

By the way when I try to use the svg in img element it does not work.

Any idea why is not showing my SVG when using as css background?

Thanks

Comment: can you add you `html/css` detail? in jsfiddle please

Comment: [All about SVG](http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/).

Comment: Actually I followed that tutorial

Comment: And when I use a different SVG from the Web, it works, so I guess it's a export issue

Comment: Make sure the relative file path is correct. For instance, if your `css/` folder is beside `img/` then you need to go up in the path by `../`. i.e. using `../img/logo.svg`

Comment: path is correct (console doesn't show 404 for the file)

Comment: Post your svg file content... or a link to it. The above link gives "404 Not found"

Comment: If you are sure your URL is correct, then another thing to check is that your web server is configured to return the correct MIME type for `.svg` files.  It should be `image/svg+xml`.

Comment: URL is correct 100% sure, can I declare the MIME type in the .svg? How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem.
It was about the server, I just added SVG support in my .htaccess

```
AddType image/svg+xml svg
AddType image/svg+xml svgz
```

Thank you